# How to save input entry in a state of component for an API call using componentDidMount and Async?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, input

I don't manage to save at each letter entry the "input" field into the state of my component, to make an API call and using componentDidMount().

I can retrieve the information via the API if I manually enter a word in the state of the component, but I don't manage to update the state "value" via the input.

Am I missing something ?
Maybe the asynchronous part that I'm just starting to discover?

```
import React from 'react'
import { Component } from "react";

class ApiMaze extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            informations: [],  //La liste contient tout les éléments récupérés dans le fetch de l'API
            value: ""
        };
    }

    // Fonction fléchée 
    handleInput = (event) => this.setState({ value: event.target.value });

    // Fonction normale 
    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }

    // Life Cycle: Se produit après que le composant soit chargée 
    async componentDidMount() {
        const url = "http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=" + this.state.value
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({informations: data})
        console.log(this.state.informations);
    }

    // Rendu final 
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" value={this.state.value} required onChange={this.handleInput} placeholder="Name of the serie" />
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div >
                    {this.state.informations.map(serie =>(
                        <div className="apiResult" key={serie.show.id}>
                            {serie.show.name}
                            <br></br>
                            {serie.show.summary}
                        </div>
                        
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ApiMaze;
```

Comment: How did you figure out that the state is not updated for `value`?

Comment: Every time I type, nothing happens at all. The field becomes empty again when I submit and nothing loads.  I added a console.log in the handleInput and in fact the input seems to be captured. So I don't understand why this is not taken into account in the state of the component.

Comment: Every time you type nothing should happen. All that needs to happen is change the value in the input. This is what your handleInput does

Answer (score 1):

The problem is ComponentDidMount does not call everytime. You can instead use componentDidUpdate. For more information on lifecycle you can check here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html.

Comment: @chris Can you please mark my answer as accepted if I could solve your query :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should work now

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      informations: [],
      value: '',
    };
  }

  handleInput = e => this.setState({ value: e.target.value });

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.handleFetch();
  };

  handleFetch = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${this.state.value}`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ informations: data });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type='text'
            value={this.state.value}
            required
            onChange={this.handleInput}
            placeholder='Name of the serie'
          />
        </form>
        <div>
          {this.state.informations.map(serie => (
            <div className='apiResult' key={serie.show.id}>
              {serie.show.name}
              <br></br>
              {serie.show.summary}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your feedback! Your method works but does not fully respond to what I want to do, an update of the render for each letter entered in the input.

Praneeth provided the answer: I just need to change the componentDidMount to ComponentDidUpdate.

Anyway, thank you for your help, I really appreciate :)